# selecting rows from 2 matrices using an indicator vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-indexing

Suppose I have a vector:

```
f = np.array([1,1,0,0]) #(4,)
```

and 2 matrices:

```
m1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]) #(4,2)
m2 = np.array([[10,20],[30,40],[50,60],[70,80]]) #(4,2)
```

How can I create a new matrix `m3` that selects rows from m1 where f == 1 and m2 otherwise?

I want m3 to be:

```
>>> m3
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [50, 60],
       [70, 80]])
```

How do I achieve this? Would prefer a solution that I can use in theano as well.

Comment: `np.vstack((m1[np.where(f==1)], m2[np.where(f!=1)]))`? I am not familiar with `theano`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Theano but for numpy:

```
np.where(f[:, None], m1, m2)
```

Comment: or `where(f,m1.T,m2.T).T`

Comment: @B.M. interesting. I would have expected your line to return a non-C-contiguous array, but it doesn't. It seems exactly equivalent to mine.